# Disable only one from the list Recyclerview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 6 list item `recyclerview` from `Json`. I'am create action click for the list item. How to disable click only one from list `recyclerview` in `android`.

Comment: what do you mean by *`Disable only one from the list`*

Comment: Disable click in the recyclerview list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in **onBindViewHolder** method:

```
if (position==2)// position which you want to disable
{
 holder.textView.setOnClickListener(null)
}else {
    holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // perform action here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks immodi... this work

Comment: @bambangoffice, you are welcome :)